# Android SOAP web client with Axis2 classes

Tags: android, soap, apache-axis, dalvik

I’m creating an Android client to a SOAP webservice. I’ve already found a bunch of topics with similar problem. Most similar one is this one: 
[Generating Java from WSDL for use on Android with ksoap2-android SOAP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124995/tool-for-generating-java-from-wsdl-for-use-on-android-with-ksoap2-android-soap-c) 
I’ve created classes from WSDL using Axis2 Code Generator. I know that they are fine because I managed to connect with the service from my computer using the Stub class. 
Now I have to transfer it to an Android and there is a problem. 
When I import all axis2 jars and one java jar (rt) I got the Dalvik error. I know that android is based on Java 5 and most of this stuff is based on java 6. But if I manage to repackage all of them will it work same as in normal Java application? Just by creating a Stub object will I be able to connect to the webservice? Or even if I repackage all this things will it make no sense and it won’t work? 
Also the axis2 generated a build.xml file. Do I need it also in my android application?  I know that if I want to repackage jars I must create one but I assume it should be different from the native java? 
I’m totally new to this topic, so this question might be stupid but I’m kinda desperate now. 
I’m not putting a code here because it’s plenty of it but if there is a need I will do it.

Comment: FYI Your English is as good as, or better than, 90% of what I see in the new user review queues, so don't worry about it.